# Overwrite Python_SITELIB set by cmake

Tags: cmake

I need to overwrite `Python_SITELIB`, which is set by `cmake` using `find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter DEVELOPMENT)`, to change the installation location. I tried `cmake .. -DPython_SITELIB="/new/path"` and `cmake .. -UPython_SITELIB -DPython_SITELIB="/new/path"`, but the following MWE still prints:

```
[...]
-- Python found: /usr/bin/python2.7
-- Python_SITELIB: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
[...]
```

MWE:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(FindPython)

# Find Python
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter DEVELOPMENT)

# Print the found Python path
message(STATUS "Python found: ${Python_EXECUTABLE}")
message(STATUS "Python_SITELIB: ${Python_SITELIB}")
```

Comment: According to documentation for [FindPython.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html) script, the variable `Python_SITELIB` contains the result of the python code `sysconfig.get_path('stdlib')`. That is, given directory is the one associated with the **Python executable**. You cannot redefine this directory, unless rebuild the Python itself. Why do you want to change the `Python_SITELIB` variable? It smells like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) for me.

Comment: I am working on a [PR](https://github.com/spack/spack/pull/39094) for spack, which uses a locally built python and stores python packages in special locations, so that they can easily be loaded during runtime. So the default store location is not an option. It would be easy if I could tell cmake to use another location, otherwise I would apply a patch to modify the CMakelist.txt